# Is the communication between wallet and remote node encrypted?

Tags: viewkey, remote-access, network, encryption

If I understand it correctly, the wallet provides the remote node with view keys so it can find the corresponding outputs, and later the wallet may also send a signed transaction for the remote node to broadcast.

Can someone listening to the communication gain access to the view keys and the transaction information, or is that communication encrypted?

Answer (score 2):

No, the wallet does not provide the remote node with the view keys. I think you are confusing this with the web wallet MyMonero which requires the view key.

The only thing that the remote node will know about you is your IP Address.

Edit: The remote node will also know what are your mixins, so best to keep changing remote nodes.

Edit: To answer your additional questions.

The connection between remote node and client (GUI or CLI) does NOT add encryption from what I read. However, the actual transactions which you broadcast your transfers are signed already by your keys - so already encrypted.

Furthermore, when connected to a remote node you have to read all transactions because on your client side you have to check if the transaction is yours. This will take some time that uses network and cpu resources.

Lastly, the remote node is useful since it alleviates the bandwidth usage  and time to synchronize with other peers in the network.

Here is some additional information that talks about what information are sent and received from the daemon (this is also applicable to a remote node)

[How much information is passed from the daemon to simplewallet when scanning for a wallet's transactions?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/how-much-information-is-passed-from-the-daemon-to-simplewallet-when-scanning-for)
[Is it safe to share a daemon with a roommate?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1134/is-it-safe-to-share-a-daemon-with-a-roommate)

Comment: That must take a while then. How long does it take to scan the block chain that way? I mean, if it is the same or longer than just downloading the full blockchain, then I don't see the use for using a remote node. // To my other question, do you know if the traffic between the user wallet and the remote node is encrypted?

Comment: edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

While secret keys are never sent to the daemon, link encryption depends on the two ends. By default, opportunistic encryption will be done, but either side can specifically disable encryption or mandate it. Encryption uses SSL. You can check whether your current connection to a daemon is encrypted by running this in monero-wallet-cli:

> status