# How can you minimize risks to your privacy when using a remote node?

Tags: full-node, nodes

If a user sends Monero through a remote node, then the remote node operator would know the originating IP of that transaction.  What are the steps that a user is able to take to reduce this potential privacy concern while using a remote node?

Comment: Kinda duplicate of https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1134/is-it-safe-to-share-a-daemon-with-a-roommate, but not quite. This will have information you will find interesting.

Comment: I'd say this is the better one: http://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/38/what-privacy-or-security-trade-offs-are-associated-with-not-running-your-own-ful , but yeah, this is different because its two questions.

OP, can you change your question to "How can you minimize risks when using a remote node?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's only about sending moneroj, one could [generate locally a signed transaction](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/2160/110) and forward it through a service like https://xmrchain.net/rawtx using tor/i2p/vpn to hide the originating IP.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the remove node will have access to your IP and can know the transactions that your wallet asked to mix yours

I dont think there is any way to prevent this, the only advice that I can think of is using diferent nodes at diferent times