# How can I use Monero without syncing the blockchain?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monero-wallet-gui, full-node, remote-access, user-guide

Suppose I have a computer that doesn't have a lot of storage space, or suppose I don't want to wait a while for the blockchain to be synced with my computer. What can I do to use Monero faster without downloading the entire blockchain to my computer?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[The Monero community encourages you to run a full node](https://getmonero.org/getting-started/running) so you can get the highest level of privacy and support the network the most. However, we understand that convenience is sometimes more important. For these instances, there are a few options:

### Use a web wallet.

This allows you to use Monero from a web browser without downloading anything, and you can use Monero wherever you have access to the webpage. I suggest [MyMonero](https://mymonero.com/) since it is run by a Monero core team member. Web wallets are the least secure of all wallets.

### Use a remote node (SPV wallet).

You have the option of downloading Monero and simply using someone else's node instead of your own. This could be a friend's or a complete stranger's. Using a remote node is less safe than using your own, but it should still be safe for most uses and it is very easy. By default, the --trusted-daemon option is off, which means that Monero will automatically obfuscate data sent to this node. Read more about [risks using a remote node here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/1137/42).

There are many users who have chosen to open their nodes for other people to use. The most commonly suggested nodes to use are the [MoneroWorld nodes](https://moneroworld.com/#nodes).

#### Command Line Interface (CLI) Wallet

If you are using the Monero **command line wallet**, you can run one of the following commands depending on your operating system when starting the Monero wallet:

**Windows**

```
monero-wallet-cli.exe --daemon-host ADDRESS.OF.HOST:18081
```

**Mac/Linux**

```
./monero-wallet-cli --daemon-host ADDRESS.OF.HOST:18081
```

#### Graphical User Interface (GUI) Wallet

If you are using the **GUI**, **use the simple mode** OR simply specify a custom daemon address in the startup screen as shown below:

[image: Monero GUI startup screen]

Alternatively, you can go to the Settings panel and change the Daemon address to the remote node of your choosing

[image: Image courtesy of MoneroWorld.com]

**What nodes can I use?**

You can use any node you know about or any of the nodes found on [this page](https://moneroworld.com/#nodes). The one I suggest using is below:

```
node.moneroworld.com:18089
```

If in the settings page of the GUI wallet, omit the :18089 part. The GUI does this automatically under this page in the box to the right (see the examples above to see whether you should use it or not). For some of the MoneroWorld nodes, use port 18081 instead. The page should clearly state which port to use.

### Use a phone wallet (SPV wallet).

You can use the [Monero Monerujo](https://monerujo.io/) wallet for Android ([Google Play link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.m2049r.xmrwallet&ah=nf4ShCqR2SODvNp2gl4_kd7Uu6Q)). This wallet automatically connects to an open node, though you can specify another remote node if you wish.

You can use [Cake Wallet](https://cakewallet.io) or [X Wallet](https://xwallet.tech) for Apple iOS. These will automatically connect to open remote nodes.

### Use a lightweight wallet.

You can use a lightweight wallet that shares your view key with a provider for greater convenience at the cost of some privacy.

[MyMonero desktop apps](https://github.com/mymonero/mymonero-app-js/releases), which automatically connects to the MyMonero backend. You can optionally point to a different service.

[MyMonero Apple iOS app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mymonero-send-money-privately/id1372508199?mt=8), which automatically connects to the MyMonero backend. You can optionally point to a different service.

[Edge Wallet](https://edge.app/) for Apple iOS and android, which connects to the MyMonero backend.

Comment: Coinomi is working to integrate XMR to their wallet.

Comment: @cryptow I will update this answer when it is released.

Comment: There is also the more niche solution of having the chain on a less secure computer which has the necessary storage space (if any is available), and using cold signing.

Comment: Can anyone point me where does the gui download the blockchain to? (in mac)

Comment: Would like to add that you only need to start syncing once you actually want to view balance/spend money. You do not need to sync if you just want to create a wallet and receive money on its address.

Comment: You need to use `--daemon-address` instead of `--daemon-host`, as the latter doesn't take custom port.