# Monero GUI wallet not syncing

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I am running windows 10 on a surface pro 4. I have 8506 blocks left and counting up. It is the newest version of the GUI. Is there a way a way I can sync up through a different localhost maybe? I am still a noob so please explain like I am a 5 year old. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean connecting to a remote node. Syncing monero sometimes can be slow for some users so just keep it running and it should synchronize and may take days.

Edit: To give you an idea, today, I just tried to synchronized starting at 98% and took me 3 hours. I'm using an SSD which is faster.

However, you can connect  to a remote node if you are really having problems. To connect to a remote node follow this guide [How can I use Monero without syncing the blockchain?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3273/how-can-i-use-monero-without-syncing-the-blockchain).