# Forgot to use Payement ID when transferring eth to Monero

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, payment-id, shapeshift

I forgot to send a Payment ID from Eth to Monero (via ShapeShift) and now the monero doesn't show up in my wallet (I use Monero's own wallet). ShapeShift says it is up to the monero wallet support to help me as the transaction went through they informed me. Who can help me on this matter?

Comment: Hello i have two PC fully synced with the Monero wallet GUI version, and i bought monero 2 weeks ago at litebit , i did not enter a payment-ID and now i did not receive my monero. But i see it here , how can i get it inside my wallet ? : https://moneroexplorer.com/ MoneroExplorer.com dvwae436pd7nt4bc.onion
Tx hash: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Tx public key: 8366d948ca1040a5292750e8199a38639858a0c312148197a57a49e0467b4b62
Block: 1604504 Timestamp [UCT]: 2018-06-27 22:36:44 Age [y:d:h:m:s]: 00:012:23:57:57 Fee: 0.002429000000 Tx size: 13.4678 kB
Checking which outputs belong to the given address

Comment: @babyface - Please see -> https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6640/i-am-missing-not-seeing-a-transaction-to-in-the-gui-zero-balance

Answer (score 1):

Payment ID is used to know from where the payments had came from, if the case was you where sending monero to shapeshift you where forced to use payment id, so shapeshift know that the transaction came from you, for receiving moneros on your own wallet this is not mandatory, the moneros should be on your wallet.. is it fully sync?

Answer (score 1):

If you **receive** Monero from ShapeShift, you don't need payment ID.

Probably your wallet did not sync yet. This means your money probably arrived, but you just can't see it (yet). Once you sync with the blockchain, it should appear.

If using **GUI**, open it and keep it running until sync completed.

If using **CLI**, start `monerod` and keep it running until sync completed. Keep it open, and start `monero-wallet-cli --wallet-file <yourWallet>`.

You need about 25GB for blockchain storage and it will be stored in your ProgramData folder on C: drive on Windows (`%programdata\bitmonero`)  or your home dir. on Linux (`~/.bitmonero`).

To avoid downloading entire blockchain, see here:

[How can I use Monero without syncing the blockchain?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3273/how-can-i-use-monero-without-syncing-the-blockchain)

Comment: Thank you both for the answers, makes the working of the payment-id clear. I do have my wallet synced. Is there any way I can see if the transaction is successful or not? The idea of the block chain is that you are able to validate that yourself right?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running 0.12 Lithium Luna? If not you're checking against the wrong chain in your wallet. Just upgrade to 0.12 and you *should* find your moneroj.

If you **are** running 0.12, then ask shapeshift to provide the *transaction ID* & *transaction's key,* and follow the [prove payment](https://getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/prove-payment.html) guide to check if the payment was really done.