# I did not receive 0.37 Monero sent from FreeWallet on my iPhone to Monero-wallet-GUI (on MacBookAir)

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I wanted to send 0.4 XMR from my FreeWallet on my iPhone 6 and after deduction of 9%, i.e. 0.03 XMR (=extremely expensive if you ask me), to my monero-wallet-GUI on my macbook air, 0.37 was sent out of my FreeWallet on Nov 26.
Since I have checked my monero-wallet-GUI and nothing has arrived.
I did the transaction using the scanner function in my FreeWallet. No transaction ID, just the address of my monero-wallet-GUI.
Why hasn't the 0.37 XMR arrived?
Can anybody tell me what possibly went wrong

Comment: Use this guide: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6640/i-am-missing-not-seeing-a-transaction-to-in-the-gui-zero-balance

Answer (score 2):

Freewallet is not a trustworthy wallet service. Please use the monero wallet binaries at getmonero.org

Answer (score 0):

Freewallet is a SCAM and they block your outgoing payments. So you will not be able to transfer it. I'm stucked for a month and support is "busy" solving my case for 4 weeks. They do not give you private key so your money is lost. Hope it will be soon criminal case against Freewallet