# Transactions Bitfinex <-> Wallet not going through since 24 hours

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, transaction-confirmation

Good Evening,

yesterday i made 2 transactions from the monero wallet to bitfinex and one withdrawal from bitfinex to monero wallet

All three transactions havent gone through.

are there any network problems recently ?

jan

Comment: I have the same issues with a XMR withdrawal transaction I did yesterday on Minergate. Is the monero network down?

Comment: It's really hard to find the answer to a question without any details. The transaction id would be the first thing to give (or any error if no transaction id was given).

Comment: @jan: Use this guide -> https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6640/i-am-missing-not-seeing-a-transaction-to-in-the-gui-zero-balance

Comment: @chitzui: Use this guide -> https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6640/i-am-missing-not-seeing-a-transaction-to-in-the-gui-zero-balance

Comment: Hello, yes, the answer for me was, that I was using a local CLI wallet and the "monerod" daemon was out of sync. After syncing the wallet I saw my balance. The best is probably to use some shared online daemons.

Answer (score 1):

So for me, it was that I used a local CLI wallet and my *monerod daemon* was out of sync. After syncing the wallet (by starting `./monerod`) I saw my balance. The best is probably to use some shared online daemons instead of a local one.