# XMR not showing and more issues

Tags: blockchain

Last week I tried to start the GUI.  It wouldn't start did some research here and found out my blockchain was corrupt.  BTW this is almost 2 weeks ago.  I erased my blockchain and started resyncing.  I forget why but i stopped the syncing for some reason I was about 100 days behind at that point.  I tried restarting and the GUI and some research here told me that my blockchain was corrupt again so I restarted again got to about 70 days behind my computer crashed and again blockchain corrupt.  Its typically taking me 3-4 days to get to this point.  I did some research found out I could download a copy of the blockchain which I did from the monero website.  That was 2 days ago.  I downloaded it and started syncing the remaining missing blocks.  The download was about 70,000 blocks behind the current height.  It shows it syncs I used the GUI last time and it showed me that I was synced to the current block.  I've had 6-8 TX go into my wallet since it crashed.  I'm 99.9% that they were deposited I've had many deposits from this source and they have always been made.  I have the tx id info but I don't want to post it here. I'd be willing to share it in private. I tried to verify one of the tx it shows 2 outputs one true one false.  I'm gonna go check a couple more but like I said I'm almost positive the payments were made. I do have a payment in GUI waiting for me to release it but I'm waiting to see where the rest of my funds are.

Before when I pressed show status it didn't show these errors but now it is.

```
Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081
Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081
Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081
Height: 1491305/1491305 (100.0%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 614.94 MH/s, v6, up to date, 0(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 0m 36s
Height: 1491305/1491306 (99.9%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 614.94 MH/s, v6, up to date, 2(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 0m 47s
Height: 1491305/1491306 (99.9%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 614.94 MH/s, v6, up to date, 3(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 0m 51s
Height: 1491312/1491312 (100.0%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 614.95 MH/s, v6, up to date, 8(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 12m 52s
```

Ive tried renaming the wallet to (wallet_name)oldzero

Ive followed and tried everything in this thread [I am missing (not seeing) a transaction to (in) the GUI (zero balance)](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6640/i-am-missing-not-seeing-a-transaction-to-in-the-gui-zero-balance)

Still my balance is zero.  I badly need some help with this.

Right now the GUI is showing syncing but its done this to me 10 times and every time my balance showed up as 0.

Comment: Did you try this part of the guide? "Still not seeing your funds? It might be that a small part of your blockchain is corrupted and it's, coincidentally, the part that contained your transaction. Perform these steps:"

Comment: Also flagging this as duplicate by the way. In addition, you can PM me on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/user/dEBRUYNE_1/) if needed such that you can share some more private information.

Comment: Alternatively, you can try this if your daemon is properly fully synced - "On the `Settings` page, look at `Wallet creation height` (it's under `Debug info`). Now change this value to `1400000` and let the wallet do the refresh."