# Transferring monero from Binance to my wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

When transferring monero from Binance to my wallet last night,
I sent monero with an address and payment ID.
Not an integrated address and payment ID.

As of now, payment will not be made to my Wallet.
If payment does not come,
Is there a solution?
Please help me.

Comment: Use that ^ guide to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this post](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6640/i-am-missing-not-seeing-a-transaction-to-in-the-gui-zero-balance) to resolve your issue.

It's most likely an issue with the GUI and not with your payment