# Send monero with Payment ID but public address, not intergated address

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

I have just sent monero from binance exchange to my monero wallet. I use Payment ID but I do not use integrated address. I used my public address. Now, how is it going on? Will I lose my coin? Thanks. Vu

Comment: If you're missing a transaction, use: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6640/i-am-missing-not-seeing-a-transaction-to-in-the-gui-zero-balance

Answer (score 2):

If you are sending funds to your own wallet, you do not need to specify a payment ID. Payment IDs and integrated addresses are only there to help differentiate senders, and do not affect whether you receive funds to your wallet. Therefore regardless of whether you used an integrated address, a payment ID, or no payment ID, you'll still receive the funds.

The reason exchanges need you to use payment IDs is because they receive funds from lots of different people, and in the absence of payment IDs, Monero's privacy mechanisms prevent them from knowing who sent what.