# Can I send monero, even if it doesn't appear in my wallet?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, shapeshift

I exchanged some BTC through ShapeShift, but my monero-wallet-gui never got the Monero. I followed the instructions [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6640/i-am-missing-not-seeing-a-transaction-to-in-the-gui-zero-balance), and it didn't work. I did verify that I got the transaction confirmed and it should be there. The wallet just doesn't say so. Right now, I've switched to local node (from a remote one) and I'm waiting for it to sync in hopes that it will resolve the situation.

I was wondering if I could just go ahead and send the monero somehow. Afterall, the blockchain still regards it as being in the possession of my wallet.

Comment: What is the `Wallet creation height` (on the `Settings` page of the GUI under `Debug info`)?

Comment: @dEBRUYNE It says 1548801. I'm on a Mac with the latest gui version, btw.  Thanks for your attention. :-)

Comment: My saga continues: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/8329/xmr-not-showing-up-in-my-gui-wallet-after-refreshing-wallet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You're right that the blockchain does know that the funds exist. The blockchain doesn't know the amounts of the funds though (due to Monero's confidential transaction encrypted payment amounts), or that you own them (due to Monero's stealth addresses). If your wallet isn't aware of the funds, it will not know how to reference those funds or create the necessary cryptographic signatures in order to spend them.