# XMR not showing up in my gui wallet after refreshing wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, shapeshift

I exchanged some BTC through ShapeShift, but my monero-wallet-gui never got the Monero. I followed the instructions [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6640/i-am-missing-not-seeing-a-transaction-to-in-the-gui-zero-balance), and it didn't work. I did verify that I got the transaction confirmed and it should be there. The wallet just doesn't say so. I'm on the latest version of the software on a Mac running Sierra. (Haven't upgraded to High Sierra yet.)

Right now, I've switched to local node (from a remote one) and I'm waiting for it to sync in hopes that it will resolve the situation. (Is there any way to speed up the sync? What I need the XMR for is a little time sensitive.)

But, from my research on [GitHub](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-gui/issues/1087) and other places, I should be able to see my balance when I switch to a remote node. What can I do next to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so it did get solved, by just waiting for the local node to sync completely. This was weird because I would have thought that using a remote node would be sufficient. I just had to wait a day. (Longest day ever!)