# Transaction to sub-address missing in GUI wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, sub-address

I'm relatively new to XMR, but am running a local node synced to the GUI (v0.12.3.0 with QT v5.7.0 on Mac). I successfully transferred coins into my primary address. I then noticed I could 'create new address,' which generated an 8xxx.... address. I then sent a txn from my primary address to this new one, however did not arrive.

The good news is that I ran the 'check transmission' using the Settings, and the transacted amount does 'prove' successfully, so I trust that this is only an issue with my GUI.

I followed the steps in this link:
[I am missing (not seeing) a transaction to (in) the GUI (zero balance)](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6640/i-am-missing-not-seeing-a-transaction-to-in-the-gui-zero-balance)

Still not seeing the sub address txn. Other ideas to find txns to sub addresses?

UPDATE: The original txn was for 0.4 XMR from the primary to the sub-address. That did appear in my 'History' list as sent txn. Now, that history list shows an amount of '0' sent for that txn, and the total balance is correct as though nothing was sent. Could the inbound have somehow netted out rather than being displayed as a separate 'inbound txn?' Of note, the Payment Proof Check correctly shows an outbound amount of 0.4.

Comment: I have seen the same behavior. However cli wallet allow easily to see the subaddresses balances. I'll be interested in a response.

Comment: So, opening the wallet with the CLI and then running 'unspent_outputs' shows the truth. The 0.4 txn is being held by its own key, apart from the balance's key, so the transaction completed properly. I'm not sure the GUI presents this in the most intuitive way if sub-accounts are supposed to be helpful for visually separating funds for internal tracking purposes, but I do see how it works. Thanks.

Comment: I do agree that the actual gui balance representation is awful when it comes to subaddresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you own a 4 XMR output that is stored in your wallet. When you send 3 XMR to Bob, you will spend that 4 XMR output, and you are creating a new 3 XMR output for Bob and a new 1 XMR change output for yourself.

This change output is not labelled as "change" in the transaction that is created. It's just an output that the wallet can see originated from you. This change does not get displayed as an incoming transaction of 1 XMR, because that would be confusing.

When you send funds from your wallet to a subaddress in the same wallet, what you're effectively doing is creating two change outputs for yourself. If you send 3 XMR to yourself, what you are doing is spending a 4 XMR output to create a 3 XMR output for yourself and a 1 XMR output for yourself. But since one of those outputs doesn't get labelled as "change" in the transaction structure, they both just look like change. So the wallet has to treat this as a 0 XMR transaction, because it can't determine anything other than that no funds were sent to a third party.

Comment: It seems you are right. See my comment above. I'll have to do a little more research into the right use cases for sub-accounts. My aim was to maintain separate tracking records for internal accounting purposes, but this blurs things too much to be useful there.

Comment: @BillLaPrise Subaddresses within the same account are not designed to be used for internal accounting, they're only for privacy protection. That's why there is the concept of having "multiple accounts", which can only be done using the CLI at the moment. Moving funds between accounts will enable you to segregate funds in the manner you intend.

Comment: Ah. Got it. I'll recalibrate my thinking.