# Balance is 0.00 or zero not showing up when gui is synced

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I have a really big problem here, im running linux mint 19, with monero x64 v0 114.1.0 gui.
I have monero in the account, first the gui would not sync, stated 109 blocks remaining, let computer run all nite, blocks were at 80 in the morning, shut down restarted, blocks were at 358, then dropped to 125 and then blocks would not sync at all.
Removed the new boron butterfly completely, and downloaded the gui package again, this time the gui would not sync.
I shut down the gui , which takes a very long time and does not shut down.
I restarted the computer and the gui, and all on a local node.
The gui is synced , and balance of my monero is missing.
Any help what to do to get my monero back?
Thank You

Comment: updated my linux mint 19, to 19.2, still the same problem, a boot strap node of 194.71.109.46 port 18089 was added by it self in the gui, when i tried to connect to a remote tor node the gui refuses to connect, switched back to a local node , balance reads zero, fully synced, restarted gui and computer, on a local node, blocks remaining 115, and now 20 minutes later , states 113 daemon blocks remaining, and history transactions missing, hopefully this gets resolved soon, never had any of these problems for years using the gui

Comment: Is there an unauthorized outgoing transaction on the `History` page? Or is the `History` page blank? Also, to be clear, is this a new wallet, existing wallet, or a wallet that you restored from the 25 word mnemonic seed?

Comment: No unauthorized transactions outgoing, history page is blank, had transactions on there a few monthas ago, also its a existing wallet, and its currently stuck on 105 blocks remaining for sync. blocks do not appear to be syncing . Also states could not connect to daemon 127.0.0.1 1, 18081. plenty of issues

Comment: 8/18/19 4:26 pm 2019 08-18-19 4:26pm | Monero "Boron Butterfly" (v0. 14.1.0- release) 2019-08-18 14:26:02.365 | Generating SSL certificate Height:1903613/1903724 (99.9%) on mainnet,not mining,net hash 317.74 MH/s v11 update needed, 6 (out)+ 0 (in) connections, uptime 0h 0d 3m 21s. ,,, gui states daemon blocks remaining 114

Comment: Can you try restarting the GUI (and daemon)? Thereafter, post the `status` output again.

Comment: dEBRUYNE, I got the gui started in local node and let it run all night 13 hours or so, and was shut off in the morning, i started it , says its synced, BALANCE ZERO 0.00000000000 again, i had monero 1.5 in the gui, so its not showing up, and this is accurate, here is the log: >>>>status [ 8-19-19 8:48am ] 2019-08-19 06:48:28.661 | Monero 'Boron Butterfly' (v0.14.1.0-release)  2019-08-19 06:48:28.662 | Generating SSL certificate  Height: 1903846/1903846 (100%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 315.88 MH/s v11, update needed, 8(out)+0(in) connections, uptime0d 13h 6m 52s

Comment: That status output looks OK. Could you perform the steps in this guide (https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6640/i-am-missing-not-seeing-a-transaction-to-in-the-gui-zero-balance) after `The following assumes you're using a remote node` (I know you are not using a remote node, but the steps will still work)?

Comment: Funds Restored in my GUI wallet , Thank You very much to dEBRUYNE ! I followed the instructions set the height to 1740000, used a remonte node and its all there and synced, cannot thank you enough at the Monero Project, have a great day !

Comment: Great to hear. You may want to switch back to your own local node though, as it offers significant privacy advantages.