# Missing money in wallet´s

Tags: wallet

I send monero to my wallet .
hash 6f314eec2c6954b666033142e16071d9abdff12334848a81b1cea523a957cda4,
amount 1.42048 xmr .
then i send it to my cold wallet 
hash 4e82af5938ef1b0086c8705148e3e3a722d8c5d4e3ca71fc59ba9b62c328202f.
now i open my mobile app and my wallet on desktop ,
amount is 0 ?!?

Comment: Have you looked at this guide? https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6640/i-am-missing-not-seeing-a-transaction-to-in-the-gui-zero-balance