# Transaction Hash with only a Confirmation

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, transaction-confirmation

Months ago I transferred Monero to a Monero GUI Wallet. It never arrived. I only have a Confirmation # but not Hash.  How can I get the Hash and/or recover/see the coins in my wallet?

Comment: Can you have a look at this guide? https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6640/i-am-missing-not-seeing-a-transaction-to-in-the-gui-zero-balance

Answer (score 0):

Confirmations are number of blocks since the tx was mined. From that number, you can deduce the block the tx is in. There will likely be several transactions though, so yours will be one of them.

A typical reason for monero not appearing in a wallet is that wallet having an incorrect setting for "refresh-from-block-height". This causes the wallet to skip transactions it thinks are too old to be yours. To fix this, run monero-wallet-cli on the wallet, and type:

> set refresh-from-block-height 0
> rescan_bc

Then quit monero-wallet-cli.