# XMR funds not showing up in my Wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, exchange

Yesterday using  the Changelly Exchange I traded BTC for XMR. The transaction said it was completed successfully but the Monero never ended up in my wallet. I contacted the Changelly exchange and they said everything went through on their part and that I should contact the my wallets support team. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you have a transaction hash / ID for the Monero transaction to your wallet? If so, please check if it is present on the blockchain by entering it at one of the block explorers.

Comment: do you received TXID and Secret transaction key from Changellysupport? if yes plz check on https://www.exploremonero.com/receipt if yot Get a transaction receipt soo you must update your wallet to 0.17.1.1 and sync

Comment: Ive been waiting since June 2020. Bought it on kraken, opened up a monero wallet and nothing.

Comment: @Tman - Can you have a look at this guide? https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6640/i-am-missing-not-seeing-a-transaction-to-in-the-gui-zero-balance