# XMR MONERO LAST ( TWO REMAINING PROCEDURE ) PENDING HELP EXPERT

Tags: exchange, xmrig, xmr.to, xmr-stak-amd, xmr-stak

(1)MONERO MINING    OK NO PROBLEM THIS PROCEDURE
(2) XMR MONING COIN POOL PAID PROCEDURE OK NO PROBLEM

(3) PROBLEM I MENTION UPLOAD IMAGE  PAID ADDRESS COINS  I EXCHANGE CONVERT THO FINAL TO WALLET USD DOLLER
PAID ADDRESS CONVERT TO USD DOLLER OR EURO CURRENCY.....
(4) THIS PROCEDURE I MIXED CONFUSED  WITHDRAW THE COIN PAID SHOW IMAGE       NEXT PROCEDURE I FOLLOW
(5) XMR MONERO OFFITIAL WALLET COIN PAID  PROCEDURE DONE BUT WITHDRAW PROCEDURE REMAING
(6 )  HELP ONLY WITHDRAW PROCEDURE PAID COIN
WHAT I Follow the next step.........

enter image description here

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you already look at this guide? https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6640/i-am-missing-not-seeing-a-transaction-to-in-the-gui-zero-balance

Comment: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lavQH.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lavQH.jpg) sir my question still same only pool paid payment transfer my wallet whichy way this step guid
xmr pool paid coin tranfer my xmr wallet step help requiered only this

Comment: Can you elaborate? Did you look at the guide I linked?

Comment: I AM NOT SEELING I AM NOT BUYING  XMR COINS  I AM MINING COMPUTER  XMR COIN     MY COIN MINING GOOD AND COIN PAID CODE ALSO SHOW  .....BUT NEXT WITHDRAW  PAID MINING COIN TO MY XMR WALLET THEN I WITHDRAW THEN STEP DISTURBED ME ONE MONTH PLEASE                  WITHDRAW          AFTER COIN POOL PAID  I ALSO UPLOAD PICTURES 5 TOP POST....

Comment: POOL PAID COIN MINING DONE           NEXT STEP TO ADD MY XMR WALLET    THIS PROBLEM NOT SOLVE ONE MONTH WHICH STEP I FOLLOW                      MY PAID COIN ADD MY XMR WALLET             THEN WITHDRAW STEP MOVE MY DIRECTION

Comment: Your wallet shows as `Disconnected`. Can you please try connecting to a remote node? https://github.com/monero-ecosystem/monero-GUI-guide/blob/master/monero-GUI-guide.md#remote-node

Answer (score 0):

Your wallet says "disconnected" that means it isnt connected to a node. You can't see transactions or do any transactions when disconnected.
Setup a local node or use a remotenode (sacrifice of privacy though)

Comment: sir i send my  telegram  account  please share me telegram https://t.me/gibygib

Comment: my offital wallet monero  connected  but any other wallet attach please explain with images   or any remotly or online calling app

Comment: Is your restore height above the transaction height? Check restore height in the settings and set it lower. Then press the button to rescan balance.

Comment: coin paid  show  done         but paid coin convert connect tranfer which method  this system please explain my english poor and                       explanation end

Comment: Use an exchange or localmonero or something else.

Comment: I AM MINING    XMR MONERO  MY MINING COIN  GIVE ME PAID CURRENT COIN              NEXT STEP  PAID COIN TRANFER  DOLLER WALLET PLEASE EXPLAIN WHERE I FIND THIS STEP CONFUSED FOR ME MANY DAYS THANKS IF YOU TEACH ME                PAID COIN TRANFER WHICH WALLET       THEN WITHDRAW SEEN STRAT

Comment: https://localmonero.co/ sell your monero here

Comment: sir coin paid just withdraw method share steps

Comment: I don't seel XMR. I can't share steps. Sorry, you have to figure out how to sell it your self.