# Stuck at 4/10 confirmations, balance locked

Tags: unlocked-balance

So, my understanding is that it takes 10 confirmations to get the XMR balance unlocked in the wallet.  I my deposited XMR from an exchange to my XMR wallet over 48 hours ago and I am at 4/10 confirmations.  Therefore I still cannot spend or access my XMR coins.  Why did I not get all 10 confirmations and more importantly how to get them moving so I can spend my coins?

Answer (score 1):

It takes 10 confirmations to be able to *spend* your received XMR. If you are stuck at only 4 confirmations after 48 hours your node is not synchronized to the network.

If you're using a remote node, use a different one. If you're using your own node, check the logs.

Also see [this Q/A](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6640/i-am-missing-not-seeing-a-transaction-to-in-the-gui-zero-balance) (which answers a very similar problem and for which the same steps can be followed in your case).

Comment: I followed all the steps under "The following assumes you're using a remote node" and my wallet is still not Synching.  I have also tried switches to multiple different remote nodes.  Checking the logs show the most up to date Height number.  I am also having issues closing the wallet from GUI.  It gets stuck at closing and I have to kill the app and monerod.exe everytime I need to close the wallet.

Comment: I also just noticed that the link above has notes from 4 years ago.  Any chance you can update them with the updated steps?

Comment: @r2defi it was last updated *this year* and is still relevant.