# Transaction is not appearing

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I have sent some Monero from my GUI wallet to another wallet of mine on Tails but it hasn’t appeared yet although it’s been more than 48 hours since I sent it.

I have done the same thing several times and this is the first time that went wrong so I don’t know what was wrong.

The address is correct. I tried some troubleshoots I can find online such as

[I am missing (not seeing) a transaction to (in) the GUI (zero balance)](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6640/i-am-missing-not-seeing-a-transaction-to-in-the-gui-zero-balance)

Is there anything I should check?

If I check the transaction with the tool, the result says

This address owns output
O with pubkey:
(Removed for this post)
This address doesn't own output 1 with pubkey: (removed for this post) for amount: Confidential

I don’t know if this means it’s been successfully sent or not.

What should I check? Thanks!

Comment: Are you connected to a remote node or to your own (local) node?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you checked the transaction ID in a Monero blockchain explorer. If the transaction ID is there with a couple hundred confirmations, that means the Wallet installed on Tails is either not using the latest version or was setup incorrectly.

By the way, did you know Monero has accounts that have different balances from each other? You don't need to use two seeds to maintain two purposes, you can use the same seed to maintain multiple accounts.