# Not seeing my Balance?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, balance

I have a problem with my GUI wallet. I can't see my transactions and balance. I bought the XMR on localmonero.co and everything went well with the trade and I transferred the XMR from my localmonero account to my XMR wallet. According to https://xmr.llcoins.net/ it worked and the coins were transferred. I followed the guide [I am missing (not seeing) a transaction to (in) the GUI (zero balance)](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6640/i-am-missing-not-seeing-a-transaction-to-in-the-gui-zero-balance) but I still don't see anything. The node I am using is node.moneroworld.com on port 18089. Node is trusted, Wallet & Daemon are synchronized. Can you please help me with this? I can also send you screenshots of my settings.

Thank you so much guys!!

Comment: Which version of the GUI are you using? You can check it on the `Settings` page -> `Info` tab.

Comment: What do you mean node is trusted?? Only set the node to trusted if you run the node. I'd also recommend using another node like support xmr since it is fast and reliable.