# Withdrawal Delay

Tags: transaction-data, transaction-confirmation

I've withdraw from Gate.io and its been more than 3 hours and the tx id that gate's gave me shows nothing. What can causes this and what is maximum transfer time on XMR ? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Why a particular exchange implements a delay (or not) has nothing specifically to do with Monero — once a Monero transaction is broadcast to the network it shows up almost instantly and gets mined in a block in 2 minutes or less.

You can check a transaction ID on well known public explorers (eg xmrchain.net). If you don't see it in your wallet, see this [QA](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6640/i-am-missing-not-seeing-a-transaction-to-in-the-gui-zero-balance).