# Transaction Not Appearing In Wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I made a transaction on local monero yesterday for some monero with my monero gui wallet on windows. It had been a few months since last bought any monero so when I purchased it my wallet wasn’t the last version (0.18.1.2) so I downloaded it after I made my purchase. I’ve only bought monero maybe around 10 times.

my transaction ID is

91f4e967c1d7e77d3c533bf0aa6a86f472d1d30007038fa39c97a155dfd05a5f

when I enter it on

https://xmrchain.net/search?value=91f4e967c1d7e77d3c533bf0aa6a86f472d1d30007038fa39c97a155dfd05a5f

and

https://localmonero.co/blocks/search/91f4e967c1d7e77d3c533bf0aa6a86f472d1d30007038fa39c97a155dfd05a5f

it finds a transaction

however, when I enter my details on

https://xmr.llcoins.net/checktx.html

and put in the transaction id, my private key/ secret view key from my wallet, and my public address / primary materials

I get message saying "Failed to get transaction data! Perhaps MoneroBlocks is down?"

I presume since I found the transaction id data that proves that the transaction happened and that the problem is with my wallet syncing the data.

I have tried some steps to sync my wallet listed here such
[I am missing (not seeing) a transaction to (in) the GUI (zero balance)](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6640/i-am-missing-not-seeing-a-transaction-to-in-the-gui-zero-balance)

such as changing wallet height to 1940000 and changing my wallet name. but still nothing I have done this multiple times.

do ye have any solutions to this problem or does monero have some sort of customer support I can talk to.

Comment: Which `Wallet mode` are you using? You can check it on the `Settings` page -> `Info` tab of the GUI.

Comment: Im having the same exact problem. Anything work for you?