# HELP ME WITH MONERO PLEASE

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, address

I am writing to you because I cannot find a solution with monero wallet.
I hope I explained myself well: I installed monero with blockchain, I made several transactions by opening multiple accounts. On Friday, after sending the last transaction on account number 3 that they entered, on Saturday I open monero wallet and it gives me the error Error: Unable to connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081 each time.
In panic I uninstalled and reinstalled the wallet, but the accounts were gone and the address of account number 3 that I had opened was not there. I uninstalled everything and reinstalled everything again with the 25 words, but I still don't see my balance.
Please help me

Comment: Please follow instructions in the linked duplicate. https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6640/i-am-missing-not-seeing-a-transaction-to-in-the-gui-zero-balance