# Disk space required nowedays?

Tags: dynamic-blocksize-limit

Oke a quick question:

How much disc space does monero need these days???

After the last time when it needed like 24gb on your windows drive.... it's now up to 32gb and counting. I've deleted already so many valuable programs just to run this wallet that i'm wondering what else i need to delete and how much more space it needs. I'm not a computer wiz so i rather delete every program on my computer rather then copy pasting things. But can anyone share how much more space it needs????

Answer (score 2):

It will need more and more as adoption grows, but you don't really need to store the entire thing (although if you can, it's generally better for you), you can connect to somoene else's node instead: [How can I use Monero without syncing the blockchain?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3273/how-can-i-use-monero-without-syncing-the-blockchain)

Last time I checked my disk it was about 32GB, could be a few more right now. Note that the database on disk will always be bigger than the .raw file. This is because database stores some additional info computed from raw data to enable fast searches etc.

Answer (score 0):

The raw block chain download from [the official website](https://downloads.getmonero.org/blockchain.raw) was 25.4 GB as of 6:23 AM on Thursday, December 7, 2017 (UTC).