# Are there any lightweight Monero wallets?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I'm new to this amazing ecoin, but a bit frustrated that I could not find any user-friendly lightweight wallet for Linux.

I have downloaded moenro-gui-linux but it takes ages to synchronize the blockchain. Hence the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a remote node to sync your **Monero** blockchain, please read the following:

[How can I use Monero without syncing the blockchain?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3273/how-can-i-use-monero-without-syncing-the-blockchain)

Answer (score 0):

You can speed the process up by downloading the blockchain from getmonero.org (currently around 30GB).

see [How to speed up initial blockchain sync](https://www.monero.how/tutorial-how-to-speed-up-initial-blockchain-sync)

However keep in mind that it is always safer to sync the blockchain yourself