# QUESTION : is it safe to use a remote monero demond (monerd)

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod, security

hello everyone i don't know about professional part of monero so my question may sound crazy excuse for that

i've seen some pool and .. provide a remote daemon for their users so they can use official wallet without download and sync of blockchain

my question is if i use these remote daemons is it possible for them to get my spend key or any access to my wallet i know that 's not possible using standard daemon that everyone can download . my question is for a modified monerod ,so technically is there anyway that they can access my moneros only by connecting to their remote daemon considering that i have 10000xmr in my wallet(just for understanding the importance ) and this is their goal
(i'm not talking about trust in any way )

i posted this question both in here and reddit because i feel here for professional after reading questions i nehre and reddit sorry for that

thanks for reading best regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it safe to share a daemon with a roommate?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1134/is-it-safe-to-share-a-daemon-with-a-roommate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only risk that you incur by using a remote node, its that if the remote node goes offline, you have to rely in another remote node.

https://moneroworld.com/ this is the most popular site where remote nodes are. I guess you are using one of the nodes listed there. Feel free to read the entire tutorial over there.

If you feel paranoid about your security, use a remote node and start the daemon from your wallet-gui (or run monerod), this way you can use a remote node connection while your monerod is syncing the blockchain data.

Once your monerod is synced, delete node parameters at monero-gui and save.

If you dont want to get full node, well, use this guide [Is there any way to construct a transaction manually?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2868/is-there-any-way-to-construct-a-transaction-manually/2916#2916)

Im yet to see someone robbed by a remote node. But again, if you worry about your security, use a full node. Kind regards...

Comment: thanks man 
the offline transaction signing was what i needed

Comment: Yes, probably. But i can tell you that you are a lil paranoid too. If remote nodes were insecure, Electrum wallet for BTC would not exist; and actually that's one of the most popular wallets.

Comment: iused mymonero for more than a year with no problem but about a month ago all i had mined in two month were stolen from mmy wallet ( i checked everything in my pc no keylogger no rat no rootkit , no phishing site in history) and i never understood how my coins were stolen 
after that i've got paranoid about coins security 

i should have 15 rep to give you one sorry for that

Comment: Well, yeah, web wallets are not as secure as desktop ones, because you have not control over your priv keys. I ended up abandoning mymonero and using desktop wallet, connected to a remote node, just bc i have limited data connection. Remember to make a physical copy of your seed, priv keys and you can make a copy of the wallet files in a usb drive (and leave that usb unused), just in case something bad happens to your desktop. Kind regards...